# Was the Mayo clinic one of the safest due to hypnotic anaesthesia in its early days?

Tags: medical-science, pain, hypnotism

> The prestigious Mayo Clinic resulted from the results of hypnotic anesthesia trance. A nurse named “Alice Magaw” was the nurse-anesthetist who assisted at all of the Mayo Brothers surgical procedures.  At the time, the death rate from incorrect dosing of chemical anesthetics was higher than the death rate from the basic surgery. [...] However, after over 14,000 successful operations in which there was not one death from the hypnotic anesthetic, the Mayo Clinic had established itself as the safest hospital in America and possibly in the world.

- Source: [Phoenix Healing Blog](http://phoenixtransformational.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/a-little-history-regarding-dave-elman-medical-hypnosis/)

Is this an accurate recounting of the history of hypnosis use in the Mayo clinic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the question is whether CRNA Alice Magaw used hyponosis as the sole anaesthetic as implied in the article linked to by your question, then the answer is, no.  She talked to her patients to quieten their fears reassuring them whilst administering chloroform or ether.  The paper she wrote describing her method of administering these gases can be read in full at the [AANA archives](http://www.aana.com/newsandjournal/Documents/imagining_0299_p33-38.pdf)